# Cucumber scenario to test REST interface to scuba diving logbooks

Tags: rest, cucumber

I am looking for ideas how to improve this cucumber scenario (testing a REST interface) and make it more concise.

```
Feature: Get list of Logbooks
    As a client, I want to get a list of a certain users logbooks so that i can present
    the logbooks name and the number of scuba dives to the user.

Scenario: Get a list of logbooks
    Given the system knows about the user "tom"
    And the user has the email "tom@tom.com"
    And he owns the logbooks
      | pacific  |
      | atlantic |
      | gulf     |
    When the client asks the system for a list of logbooks owned by user
    Then the client gets a list with 3 logbooks
    And all logbooks of the list have the users name
    And all logbooks of the list have the users email
    And one logbook has the name
      | pacific  |
      | atlantic |
      | gulf     |
    But if the user has no logbook
    And the client requests a logbook from the system
    Then the client gets an error message
```

Details:
A client (browser/other service) is accessing a logbook service via REST. The client can ask with a user name and an email address the system about a list of logbooks (named pacific, atlanic and gulf) the user might have stored at the system. In case the user has no logbooks stored, a error message is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would update what has been given, but below there are some points for further improvement.

```
Feature: Get list of Logbooks
    As a client
    I want to get a list of a certain users logbooks 
    So that i can present the logbooks name and the number of scuba dives to the client.

Background:
    Given the user "tom" has the email "tom@tom.com"

Scenario: Get a list of logbooks
    Given "tom" owns the logbooks:
      | pacific  |
      | atlantic |
      | gulf     |
    When the client requests for a list of logbooks owned by "tom"
    Then the client gets a list with 3 logbooks
    And the requested logbooks should have the users name and email
    And the requested logbooks should have the names:
      | pacific  |
      | atlantic |
      | gulf     |

Scenario: The user has no logbooks
    Given "tom" owns no logbooks
    When the client requests for a list of logbooks owned by "tom"
    Then the client should see the message "tom has no logbooks"
```

**WAYS TO IMPROVE**

BDD is all about conversations.

Cucumber being a BDD tool means that it helps with breaking down the conversational barriers between the business and the development team. You should be agreeing on the language that is used with both the dev team and business before the feature file has been completed.

Is the language stated in the scenarios the same language that the business and the dev team have agreed to use? If not, update the language. (`And the requested log books should have the users name and email`, for instance)

Are there any extra steps that the business wants to know about? If so, add them in.

Are there any steps that aren't needed? If so, remove them.